# Run NodeJs server inside Electron Builder app for production

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, adonis.js

I configured my application with [ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/) and [AdonisJS](https://adonisjs.com/).

Adonis works normally on port 3333 in localhost when I am in development mode.
This is my Electron main.js:

```
    'use strict'
//Adonis server
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');    
const cp = require('child_process');
var path = require("path");
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

let mainWindow

async function startAdonis() {
    cp.execFile('node', [`${path.join(__dirname,'server.js')}`, !isProd?'--dev':'']);
}

async function createWindow () {   
    // Create the browser window.     
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }}) 

    await startAdonis();

    //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    // and load the index.html of the app.     
    mainWindow.loadURL("http://127.0.0.1:3333")   


    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null
    });
}      

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "adonis-electron",
  "version": "4.1.0",
  "adonis-version": "4.1.0",
  "description": "The fullstack application boilerplate for Adonisjs with Electron",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "node ace test",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "adonisjs",
    "adonis-app"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/ace": "^5.0.8",
    "@adonisjs/auth": "^3.0.7",
    "@adonisjs/bodyparser": "^2.0.5",
    "@adonisjs/cors": "^1.0.7",
    "@adonisjs/fold": "^4.0.9",
    "@adonisjs/framework": "^5.0.9",
    "@adonisjs/ignitor": "^2.0.8",
    "@adonisjs/lucid": "^6.1.3",
    "@adonisjs/session": "^1.0.27",
    "@adonisjs/shield": "^1.0.8",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "^22.6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "App": "./app"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.adelec.dev",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    }
  }
}
```

When I do a yarn start, Electron starts, the server http://127.0.0.1:3333 also starts, the application works normally.

Then, I use [Electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to package the application for production on a Windows machine.
After packaging, launches the .exe file, the application opens but the http://127.0.0.1:3333 server does not start. So the application does not work.

**I am new to Electron, I do not know how to configure the server http://127.0.0.1:3333 for use use in production.**
With ExpressJs instead of AdonisJs, I have the same problem.

How to run my application in production on any Windows machine after the build?
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hi, @kouakou alexy. I'm sure your server file is not being embedded after build.

Comment: Let me check your project structure

Comment: As well, instead `const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';`

Comment: Recommend you to use `electron-is-dev`

Comment: Are there any reason you start the server as a child process, and not as a part of the main process? You could just expose a method in server.js which main.js can call to start it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having a very similar problem.